# equals() method not detecting word from file

Tags: java, file, io, java.util.scanner, equals

I am writing a program to read a file and check each line for a specific word. I have this code below, however the code does not execute the 'if statement' and I am not sure why. The file called "scores.txt" consists of:

```
Andy 60  
Bob 87  
Alice 59
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void scoreCheck() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner("scores.txt");
        int lineNum = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            lineNum++;

            if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("bob")) { 
                System.out.println("user Found On: " + lineNum);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get it to find the line which the user bob exists on. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Scanner` constructed with a `String` *reads* **that** `String`. You need to change

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("scores.txt");
```

to

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("scores.txt"));
```

Also, the `line` isn't `"Bob"` - so you probably want to change

```
if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("bob")) {
```

to something like

```
if(line.toLowerCase().startsWith("bob")) {
```

**or** you might use a `Pattern` and `matches()` (which tests for an entire match). Like,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("bob", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
if (p.matcher(line).matches()) {
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work however only works when user enters "bob" during prompt but does not work when user enters "Bob" is there any ignoreCase method? Thanks

Comment: `if(line.toLowerCase().startsWith("Bob".toLowerCase())) {`

Comment: @SakshamInABox You could also use a `Pattern`. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

On the second time it loops, `line` will have a value of `Bob 87`, just before checking `line.equalsIgnoreCase("bob")`, and even if we ignore the case, "bob" isn't equal to "bob 87"

What you need to do in your condition is `line.toLowerCase().startsWith("bob")`

Comment: Nice solution to OP's problem.